# Run MySQL Script on remote Server

Tags: mysql, ssh

I have a MySQL server installed in a remote Ubuntu VM that i access using a VPN and i have some sql scripts that i want to run on that server, to create new Stored procedures and queries.
The the details of the virtual machine are:
`IP: 192.168.58.61`
`Hostname: les12a.fi.fr`

I am using putty and i am writting directly the commands, but i would like to run directly a script that is on my Windows machine.
I have tried using Source, and path but this works fine when MySQL is on my machine. What is the correct syntax to do that on remote server?

Comment: you have to either scp the file over or use something like python fabric

Comment: how i have to do to scp the file, i usualy do not use command  line terminal, do you have an example or a link that i can use to learn a bit more?

Comment: read the putty documentation

Answer (score 4):

just do:

shell> mysql -u user -p -h HOSTNAME DBNAME < yourscript.sql

HOSTNAME: put the hostname if could be resolved or the ip of the remote server

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

SSH to your server, and then run:

`mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME < scripts.sql`

Obviously, your scripts should be stored in **scripts.sql**, which should be in your working (current) folder.

Comment: MySQL Server and script are on different machines, does it works ?

Comment: Copy the script to the server where you're executing the command first. You could use `scp`, but I don't know if that works on Windows, so if I was you, I'd install WinSCP: https://winscp.net/eng/download.php